# TYPO3: Override translation of labels in extension ke_search with TypoScript

Tags: typo3

I want to override language labels in the TYPO3 extension `ke_search`.

I've tried the following code:

```
plugin.**ke_search**._LOCAL_LANG {
    default {
        num_results = %s results:
    }
    de {
        num_results = %s Ergebnisse:
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work.
Can anyone tell me the right syntax?!

Thanks!

(I've tried tx_kesearch, ke_search_pi1, tx_kesearch_pi1/2/3 too...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on which plugin you use, it must be `plugin.tx_kesearch_pi1`, `plugin.tx_kesearch_pi2` or `plugin.tx_kesearch_pi3`. Please check the [TypoScript file](https://github.com/tpwd/ke_search/blob/master/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.typoscript) which is delivered with the extension.

If that doesn't work out, you can copy the templates from the extension into your sitepackage or any other custom directory [as described here](https://docs.typo3.org/p/tpwd/ke_search/5.0/en-us/Templating/CustomTemplates.html) and than add completely new language labels.

By the way: the extension ke_search is almost [completely translated](https://crowdin.com/project/typo3-extension-kesearch/de) into German. You can fetch the translation into your installation via the install tool. If you think your translation change is helpful for others as well, feel free to suggest a change of the translation in Crowdin.

Comment: Maybe you can post another comment, which solution exactly helped you. That will help others in the future with similar problems.

Comment: I need to override the templates, overriding just the language-tags doesn´t work in my case. May because of the special setting.

Answer (score 0):

For French labels (maybe for other translations too), the French translation seems to be available in Crowdin, but Frontend does not take it into account.

As I don't want to copy the ke_search templates to have as few conflicts as possible during future updates of ke_search, here is the solution that works for me:

1.- Copy the language file(s) that interest me to the Resources/Private/Language/Overrides folder (You do not have to create the Overrides folder, it was my choice)

2.- In the ext_localconf file, add the lines:

```
// Override the French version of the locallang of KeSearch
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['locallangXMLOverride']['fr']['EXT:ke_search/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_searchbox.xlf'][] = 'EXT:' . $extensionKey . '/Resources/Private/Language/Overrides/fr.locallang_kesearch_searchbox.xlf';
```

- Change “fr” to your language
- $extensionKey contains the key for your extension

3.- Clear all the caches